# How to order by custom property in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below tables

**Order**

```
Id    Name<br>
--    -------
1    test1<br>
2    test2<br>
3    test3<br>
```

Order_property

```
id   order_id   name   value<br>
--   --------   ----   --------
1     1         test4   11<br>
2     1         test5   22<br>
3     2         test4   33<br>
4     2         test5   44<br>
5     3         test4   55<br>
6     3         test5   66<br>
```

I wanted to find all the orders. order by value having name = 'test4' .

How should i write a querty. Please suggest

Comment: name in which table?

Comment: To clarify the quesion, please post the needed result. Also, What have you tried so far? Please post your code to get some help.

Comment: I want records "order by" value

Comment: Which order by? Simply `order by value`?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind to the tables together.

```
select * from orders o, order_property op where o.id = op.order_id order by op.name
```

Comment: I want records "order by" value

Comment: I want all the ordres not op.name = 'test4' however sorted by (op.value and name = 'test4')

Comment: @Prashant specify the *wanted* the result in your question.

Comment: I want query something like<br> select o.* from orders o, order_property op where o.id = op.order_id order by op.name order by (op.value having name = 'test4')

Answer (score 0):

First of all name column is repeated unnecessary try to avoid duplicate entries,

If order &  Order_property are referring tables names also must match

Query for given example

```
     Select o.*,op.* from orders o
     INNER JOIN order_property op ON o.id = op.order_id 
     where op.name = 'test4' order by op.value
```

Hope that works

Comment: I want records "order by" value

Comment: Select o.*,op.* from orders o
     INNER JOIN order_property op ON o.id = op.order_id 
     where op.name = 'test4' order by  op.value

Comment: I want all the ordres not op.name = 'test4' however sorted by (op.value and name = 'test4')